# Plot cannot be properly displayed

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to plot a bar chart for my data but I don't know why I kept getting "matplotlib depreciation warning" when I run the cell. Here are the codes and I would greatly appreciate your help since I just started to learn python.

```
#make an empty plot
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(30,20))

#plotting
ax0 = fig1.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax0.bar(plot_set, height = 10)

#set labels
x_label = ["January", "Febury", "March", "April", "May", "June"]
x_title = ["Month"]
y_title = ["Number of flights"]

ax0.set_ylabel(y_title)
ax0.set_title('Impact of COVID-19 on airlines')

x = np.arange(len(x_label))
ax0.set_xticks(x)
ax0.set_xticklabels(x_label)
ax0.set_xlabel('x_title')

plt.show()
```

Comment: What does the variable `plot_set` contain? Which line gives exactly which warning? Did you try `y_title = "Number of flights"` without the square brackets?

Comment: Hi Johan，plot_set is just the dataset I am using. Sorry for the confusion. I took your suggestion of removing brackets for y_title and an empty plot could be displayed. But no data was displayed. My dataset is a list of numbers is it going to be the problem? Anyway thanks for your help!

Comment: Please add a toy dataset a bit similar to `plot_set`. Is your dataset a 1D list of 6 numbers? There are too many ways to provide *"just a dataset"*.

Comment: Appreciate it man. I have figured it out. It turns out that the problem is with AX.bar function which does not have the 'x' argument. Thanks for helping me.